# This processor does not support XSAVE. This machine cannot be powered on

Tags: vmware

I have a problem with **VMware**. When I try to power on my **Windows 7 VM**, [**this error appears.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHLQt.png)
Just a week ago, I was able to power on this virtual machine. And I also recently installed **WSL** (**Windows Subsytem for Linux**), so maybe it's beacuse of it...?

How to fix that?

Comment: The newest version of VMware should co-exist with Hyper-V / WSL newest versions.  Try uninstalling VMware, restart computer, and then reinstalling VMware.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try.

Comment: So, _does_ your CPU support XSAVE? Was there perhaps a VMware Workstation(?) update? Did you enable the “Virtual Machine Platform” Windows feature?

Comment: Yes, my CPU supports XSAVE and yes, I enabled this feature.

Comment: " I also recently installed WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), so maybe it's because of it...?" - No;  The cause of this error absolutely is NOT due to WSL.  WSL2 does not even required Hyper-V;  What version of VMWare Workstation are you using exactly?

Comment: I'm using version 16.1.0

Comment: Oh no. I reinstalled VMware and this error still appears.

Comment: Maybe enabling Hyper-V through "Turn windows features on or off"?

Comment: You could try disabling both Hyper-V and WSL, restart and try VMware again to see if that helps.

Comment: That also didn't work. :(

Comment: Make a new test Guest machine. Maybe the existing Windows 7 guest got damaged.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work on new virtual machines too.

Comment: Wait, I know! Maybe it's beacuse of latest Windows updates. I was updating 2 days ago. :O

Comment: I have VMware Workstation V16 newest with Windows 10 20H2 newest and all my guest machines (one dating back 2 decades) all work. So I would be very surprised if Windows Updates were the reason.

Comment: Yeah, I have Windows 20H1, so it can be different.

Comment: Try Updating Windows.  See if that helps.

Comment: To 20H2 or updates for 20H1? (I don't have any updates for 20H1)

Comment: Ok, sorry. There is an update. :)

Comment: Update to 20H2 and then do all the Windows updates.

Comment: Ok, I will do that!

Comment: What processor do you have exactly?  VMWare has specific processor requirements

Comment: it can't be CPU fault, beacuse everything was working before.
and @John I updated to 20H2 successfully and it didn't fix anything.

Comment: @Dogramming - I cannot answer your question without that information. There is virtually no difference between 2004 and 20H2.  With the enablement patch there is no difference

Comment: It appears something has happened in the operating system. You have disabled Hyper-V / WSL and reinstalled VMware without success. So I think you need to try a Windows 10 Repair Install. I will post an answer for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Background:**

- VMware Guests were working and stopped working.
- Hyper-V /WSL disabled but did not help.
- VMware V16.1 reinstalled but did not help.
- VMware works on many different processor types (long time use of VMware Workstation.

**Possible Solution:**

**Windows User Profile damage.**  Make a new, test, Windows User Account. Log into the new Windows Account and test VMware operation.

**Windows 10 Repair Install.**  There are 3 possible methods in the steps below. Try Keep Everything and if that does not work, try the third method. Read through the steps first and then try the first option - Keep Everything.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Comment: I do not know who or why this was downvoted.  Answer is accurate

Answer (score 3):

By enabling “Virtual Machine Platform”, you enabled the Hyper-V hypervisor. This is required for WSL 2, which is based on Hyper-V. It is *not* required for WSL 1. So maybe just disable it if you don’t really need WSL 2.

When the Hyper-V hypervisor is running, VMware Workstation/Player cannot access the CPU’s virtualization features. Instead, they are forced to use Hyper-V. In the early days, this was not possible, but it is now.

The error message you get, “The processor does not support XSAVE. This virtual machine cannot be power on.” means that your CPU does not meet the requirements for using VMware products on top of Hyper-V. From the [VMware Workstation 15.5.5 Release Notes](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.5/rn/VMware-Workstation-1555-Pro-Release-Notes.html):

> Windows 10 host VBS support:  VMware Workstation 15.5.5 now runs on Windows hosts with Hyper-V features (For example: virtualization based security) enabled.
>
> The followings are minimum requirement to run VMware Workstation on a Hyper-V enabled host:
>
> CPU Requirements:
>
> - Intel Sandy Bridge or a newer CPU
> - AMD Bulldozer or a newer CPU
>
> Supported Host Operating Systems:
>
> - Windows 10 20H1 build 19041.264 or newer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

- Just turn off hyper-v by this code in cmd (administrator)

  ```
  bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
  ```
- Then restart

If you want to enable it again you can do it by this code in cmd:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```